# do While loop. It doesn't work

Tags: c

I'm really new to `C` and I can't get this while loop to work. It just exits the loop for no apparent reason.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int min;
    int max;
    int random;
    int guess;
    char user='x';

    printf("Please insert min number:");
    scanf("%d",&min);

    printf("Please insert max number:");
    scanf("%d",&max);

    random = (rand()%(max-min))+ min;

    do
    {
        printf("please insert your guess:");
        scanf("%d",&guess);

        if(guess==random)
        {
            printf("YOU WON");
            user=='y';
        }
        else if(guess!=random)
        {
            printf("UNLUCKY,would you like to play again:x for yes");
            user=='x';
        }
    }while(user=='x'); 

}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Im sorry, but how do you do that for future reference.

Comment: No worries, it's not a problem of the question, just more pleasing to the eye is all. You can do this in a lot of ide's, e.g. visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a comparison, not an assignment:

```
       user=='y';
```

You need to change it to:

```
       user='y';
```

(Note the single `=`.)

The same goes for the other assignment.